# Couchbase to PouchDB not syncing existing docs

Tags: javascript, couchbase, pouchdb, couchbase-sync-gateway

Couchbase 6.6 with Sync-gateway 2.8

My Pouchdb app can save a doc and it will replicate bidirectional with my Couchbase.
The existing docs in Couchbase are not syncing to PouchDB nor can I use alldocs function to receive
existing docs from Couchbase.

sync-gateway-config has this

```
"databases": {
    "testing": {
            "import_docs": true,
            "enable_shared_bucket_access": true,
            "bucket": "testing",
            "server": "http://xxxxxx:8091",
            "username": "sync_gateway",
            "password": "password",
            "num_index_replicas": 0,
            "users":{
            "GUEST":{
                    "disabled":false,
                    "admin_channels":["*"]
                }
            },
            "revs_limit": 20
        },
```

I have no console error as if pouchDB thinks it is working fine.

Any help is appreciated,
thanks

Comment: I have cleared site data and restarted the app and I only get the two records that were entered from the app before, none of the existing records from Couchbase. Couchbase shows all 1300+ records including the two from the app.

Comment: went back a version to Couchbase 5.5 and reloaded data.
Data looks good but same issue, pouchdb only sees new docs from app, no existing doc from couchbase are hsown.

Comment: What happens when you call the addDocs REST API directly using any HTTP client ? Share the request and response. Also enable debug level logging on sync gateway and check sync gateway logs for messages that may provide more indication of whats going on.

Comment: Posting the germane pouchDB code would be helpful.

Comment: Was this issue resolved?

Comment: Not resolved, when to standard CouchDB and started over.